# Show effective/actual author and committer used by Git

Tags: git

### Is there a Git command to display author and committer which would be used in the next commit based on all configuration sources applied?

One of the reason for this question is that I cannot find `username` (committer reported in example below) in any of the files:

```
grep -r obsdev .git/config ~/.gitconfig /etc/gitconfig
# no output
```

Apparently, there is another configuration source.

The point is that I don't want to learn about any possible configuration source existing now, or in the future, or order in which they apply and override each other. Instead, I want to let Git figure out and display final/effective author/committer values.

### Example

Under some conditions (like command line option `--author`) Git displays  commented out `Author:` and `Committer:` fields in editor for commit message:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting              
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.             
#                                                                               
# Author:    First Last <first.last@example.com>                               
# Committer: username <username@localhost.localdomain>                              
#   
...
```

**Is there a way to show these fields without trying to make a commit?**

**Alternatively**, is it possible to force Git provide comments containing `Author:` and `Committer:` fields in the commit message editor **under any circumstances** without any command line options even when defaults are used (without overriding defaults)?

Comment: You could use the `--dry-run` flag to not actually make a commit. What do you need that info for if not for committing?

Comment: **(1)** @knittl, option `--dry-run` does not show author/committer. **(2)** It's true that ultimately all I need is to make sure that commits I will actually make use proper author/committer. However, I don't want to wait until then (I might forget later). I want to make sure now that configuration is fine. **(3)** Moreover, if `git commit` is used in its default case (for example, without `--author` option), author often is not shown in the commit message editor. In other words, **you don not know which author/committer is used most of the time!** Any (new) misconfigured host is the problem.

Comment: git uses the value from the config (you can retrieve it with `git config user.name; git config user.email`), or from `$GIT_{COMMITTER,AUTHOR}_{NAME,EMAIL}` environment variables if set. Environment variables take precedence over the config values.

Comment: @knittl, yes, it makes it clear what is one more possible configuration source and that it is the last one which ultimately overrides (just like in many other *nix commands by convention) - voting up. However, being able to _show_ author/committer by a Git _command_ or _force_ Git to show them _always_ in commit editor is what I actually want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built in way to do that in Git. Git uses the config values `user.name` and `user.email`, which can be overridden by the environment variables `$GIT_{COMMITTER,AUTHOR}_{NAME,EMAIL}`.

A simple shell script should get you the info you want:

```
NAME=$(git config user.name)
EMAIL=$(git config user.email)

echo "Author:    ${GIT_AUTHOR_NAME:-$NAME} <${GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL:-$EMAIL}>
echo "Committer: ${GIT_COMMITTER_NAME:-$NAME} <${GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL:-$EMAIL}>"
```

See also [git whoami](https://github.com/petere/git-whoami)

Comment: I'm thinking, isn't `git config` command <s>exactly</s> what I was looking for? Well, yes, it does not report combined value of `NAME <EMAIL>` as it is used in commits. It is also wrong if there environment variables override values from configuration files. However, it solves my specific problem of making sure the values are properly **configured** in the files. It's been too many cases when commits come from unconfigured machines - rewriting history to fix them is just too much of hassle. Thanks for persistence to provide valuable answer!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `git var`:

```sh
# show the author (sed is there to strip the timestamp)
git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT | sed -r 's/( [^ ]+){2}$//'
# and the committer
git var GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT | sed -r 's/( [^ ]+){2}$//'
```

But if you haven't configured your name and email, it will print a warning instead of giving a value. A workaround would be:

```sh
# show the author
git var -l | grep -E '^GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT=' | sed -r 's/^[^=]+=//;s/( [^ ]+){2}$//'
# and the committer
git var -l | grep -E '^GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT=' | sed -r 's/^[^=]+=//;s/( [^ ]+){2}$//'
```

Comment: Thanks for `git var`! It's a powerful source of Git data. - I've never heard of this command. And it also correctly handles `GIT_{COMMITTER,AUTHOR}_{NAME,EMAIL}` env vars. Unfortunately, I can only accept one answer.

Comment: @uvsmtid: you can always un-accept an answer and re-accept a later post, if it answers your question better.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, besides it being simple, short and beautiful ;)